# Resume background music after using AVCaptureSession which addOutput with AVCaptureMovieFileOutPut

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudiosession

I am using AVCaptureSession method addOutput with AVCaptureMovieFileOutput object. As soon as addOutput gets called, background music gets killed, and what I do is I call removeOutput when video recording is done. But the background music won't be resumed.
I tried the code as blow:

```
AVAudioSession *audioSession=[AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
if (audioSession) {
       [audioSession setActive:NO withOptions:AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptionNotifyOthersOnDeactivation error:nil];
}
```

But it does't work for me.

Furthermore, I tried the MPMusicPlayerController method as blow:

```
MPMusicPlayerController *mp = [MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer];
[mp play];
```

It can resume system music, but it doesn't go well for 3rd part apps.

Is there any other methods can fix this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In target Capabilities background modes enable and check Audio,Airplay

```
 NSURL *soundUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"Audiourl"];
 audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundUrl error:nil];

 [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
 [audioPlayer play];
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean add these code when I remove the AVCaptureSession? In my app, I don't need to support playing music in background, I only want to resume the music from other 3rd part music apps, after recording video done.

Comment: [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO withOptions:AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptionNotifyOthersOnDeactivation error:nil];